# I cannot create a user with an encrypted homedir

Tags: 11.10, encryption, users, home-directory

In previous versions of Ubuntu you could create users with encrypted partition from the "User Accounts" GUI utility. Now this option is absent from Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric). How can you create a user with encrypted homedir in 11.10. Command line instructions acceptable! :)

Answer (score 3):

**adduser** is a perl script that takes care of the details of adding a user and will do what was removed in GNOME3

```
sudo adduser --encrypt-home USERNAME
```

If you upgrade to 11.10 from for example 11.04 then use

```
sudo adduser --uid OLD_UID --encrypt-home OLD_USERNAME
```

Make sure to use the same password as the old accounts, use `ls -lan /home` to find OLD_UID.

Comment: Thanks JBB. That solved  my question!


P.S. Is there a way to mark this as "Solved" like on answers.launchpad.com?

Comment: You just need to select one of the answers by clicking on the tickmark.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about an encrypted home partition but to add users

`sudo useradd -m -p PASSWORD USERNAME`

OR

`sudo adduser USERNAME`

may also do the trick accoording to their manuals

Answer (score 0):

The lack of graphical way to add a user with an encrypted home in Ubuntu versions using GNOME 3 is documented in [bug #816669](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/816669).